# Combining two SQL result sets into one

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have a Table-A in mysql or any other database and I want to find the counts for each value appearing in every column using the below SQLs:

Table A:

```
    Col1 Col2 Col3
Row1  A   C    E
Row2  A   C    F
Row3  B   D    G


select Col1, count(*) from Table-A group by 1, order by 2 desc;
select Col2, count(*) from Table-A group by 1, order by 2 desc;
select Col3, count(*) from Table-A group by 1, order by 2 desc;
```

When I run these queries individually the answer set would be like below:

```
Col1  count(*)
A      2
B      1

Col2  count(*)
C      2
D      1

Col3  count(*)
E      1
F      1
G      1
```

Is there any way I can write the above queries that I get one consolidated answerset like below:

```
Col1    count(*)    Col2  count(*)    Col3 count(*)
A      2              C      2          E     1
B      1              D      1          F     1
NULL   NULL       NULL    NULL          G     1
```

Comment: Mysql, oracle, and teradsta are all different rdbms products with different implementations of sql. Removed the conflicting product tags. Pls add the one back that you actually use.

Comment: Pls also consider handling data display formatting requirements in the application logic as opposed to sql.

Comment: @Shadow added the relevant tag. There is no application logic at the moment, I am just looking at some sample data and would like to format using mysql, if possible

Comment: It may be possible, but the code will get very-very ugly as the three dataset as disparate, so the only common identifier would be the row numbers of each summary record. Unless you know in advance which columns will have the most distinct values, you would need to use full outer join to combine the results, otherwise records could be dropped from the result with more records if it is on the wrong side of a join. But mysql does not support full outer join, you would have to use a combination of multiple joins and unions to emulate a single full outer join. I strongly advise you to forget this.

Comment: Oh, and if you use mysql v5, then the code for row numbers is also not particularly nice.

Comment: OK, noted, thanks. But my follow up question then is which problems should I look to solve using SQL, and which I shouldn't bother with since they are not worth it the time in SQL or better handled somewhere else like you suggested, in application logic?

Comment: Enumerate rows in each separate query. Join rows by this number.

Comment: @Code_Jamer your selects should focus on getting the data out in the most efficient manner possible. Formatting data for display should not be a concern for sql statements as those parts are often costly (as you are finding out) or can cause other issues downstream. As an example of the latter is formatting amounts to display currency signs (e.g. $100 instead of 100). This changes the output data type to string, which sorts differently from numbers.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit painful, but you can use aggregation and `union all`:

```
select max(case when which = 'col1' then col end) as col1,
       max(case when which = 'col1' then cnt end) as col1,
       max(case when which = 'col2' then col end) as col2,
       max(case when which = 'col2' then cnt end) as col2,
       max(case when which = 'col3' then col end) as col3,
       max(case when which = 'col3' then cnt end) as col3
from ((select Col1 as col, count(*) as cnt, 'col1' as which,
              row_number() over (order by cnt desc) as seqnum
       from a
       group by col1
      ) union all
      (select Col2, count(*) as cnt, 'col2' as which,
              row_number() over (order by cnt desc) as seqnum
       from a
       group by col2
      ) union all
      (select Col3, count(*) as cnt, 'col3' as which,
              row_number() over (order by cnt desc) as seqnum
       from a
       group by col3
      ) 
     ) cc
group by seqnum;
```